# JSF not loading managed beans

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, embedded-jetty

I got a simple demo project with embedded Jetty and JSF (Primefaces). The problem is that my beans are not loaded at all.

/src/main/java/HelloBean.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ... 

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy(){
        System.out.println("PRE DESTROY");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        System.out.println("POST CONSTRUCT");
    }

    public HelloBean() {
        System.out.println("Hello Bean instantiated");
    }
    ...
}
```

/src/main/webapp/index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Conti Diagnose</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="#{helloBean.name}"/>
...
```

/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>dark-hive</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>de</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>lang.lang</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

The output is

```
2014-10-30 10:13:11.525:INFO::main: Logging initialized @164ms
2014-10-30 10:13:11.633:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.0.M0
Okt 30, 2014 10:13:11 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMATION: Mojarra 2.2.8-02 ( 20140915-1602 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.8-02@13678) für Kontext '/ui' wird initialisiert.
Okt 30, 2014 10:13:12 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMATION: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
Okt 30, 2014 10:13:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFORMATION: Monitoring file:/C:/.../src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Okt 30, 2014 10:13:13 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFORMATION: Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
2014-10-30 10:13:13.157:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@538540a3{/ui,[file:///.../target/classes/../../src/main/webapp/, file:///.../target/],AVAILABLE}
2014-10-30 10:13:13.221:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5aa85b18{HTTP/1.1}{localhost:8080}
2014-10-30 10:13:13.222:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1864ms
```

The class to start the embedded server is /src/main/JettyRunner.java. The main method is:

```
InetSocketAddress address = InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("localhost", 8080);
Server server = new Server(address);

WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext();
wac.setContextPath("/ui");
wac.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.xhtml" });
String webappDir=JettyRunner.class.getClassLoader().getResource(".").toString();
wac.setBaseResource(new ResourceCollection(new String[] {
        webappDir+"../../src/main/webapp","./target" }));

server.setHandler(wac);
server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
server.start();
server.join();
```

The messages in postConstruct or the Constructor are not printed at all. Accessing a property of this bean in my xhtml gives no error and just prints nothing.

Even if I access a bean that does not exist, there's no error message.

Why are my beans not loaded?

Comment: Can you show your imports and your xhtml file ?

Comment: Added it to my post.

Comment: Just to be clear, in your bean you have `private String name` with getter and setter, you set some value to it (for example, in the constructor), and you access it with `#{helloBean.name}`?

Comment: Yes of course, it's just not included in the example above, because the "POST CONSTRUCT" doesn't even get printed.

Comment: One tiny little detail I spot is that you declare servlet specification 2.4 in your web.xml, you should use at least version 2.5.

Comment: The main reason why I asked is because of `<h:outputText value="HelloBean.name"/>`. Value should be `value=#{helloBean.name}`, so I'm not sure if that's the real code or is it a typo

Comment: Thats a typo in my post. Real code is `<h:outputText value="#{helloBean.name}"/>`

Comment: I just saw that you have `eager = true`, so I had a wrong assumption about the cause of this, sorry.

Comment: I added `<h:outputText rendered="#{helloBean == null}" value="instance is NULL"/>`and `<h:outputText rendered="#{helloBean.name == null}" value="prop is NULL"/>` to my view, and both texts are shown. So it seems like the bean is null,  but why?

Comment: @k_wave You still haven't responded to my comment about the servlet specification version. You also haven't fixed the typo in the question yet and its a very important fix - if you leave it in you can be sure to get that as answers from people who don't read through all the comments.

Comment: @Gimby I've changed to version 2.5 now, didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @k_wave Good, another thing to scratch off the list. I'm sorry but I need to be a pest: when you do the "JSF is working" test and just output a static String rather than the bean property, what is the generated HTML source in the browser (view page source)? The literal JSF tags are not in there?

Comment: JSF is rendered and interpreted as you would expect it - no JSF tags left in the browser version. Even the debug menu can be opened. Just everything accessing beans is not working.

Comment: Well... I see absolutely nothing wrong with any of what you have posted. Just for the heck of it, what if you turn the ApplicationScoped annotation into a RequestScoped one? Does that have any effect at all?

Comment: No that has no effect. Seems like JSF totaly ignores my beans. I've created a minimal (not-)working example. It's a eclipse maven project and can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3vweRLsoKiuNlc4OF9aLVRLWG8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After three days I finally found the answer myself:

Just added the line

```
wac.setResourceAlias("/WEB-INF/classes/", "/classes/");
```

to my runner class. Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding the `@Named` annotation to your bean. This annotation makes the managed bean accessible through the EL. Then change

```
<h:outputText value="HelloBean.name"/>
```

to

```
<h:outputText value="#{HelloBean.name}"/>
```

in /src/main/webapp/index.xhtml

Comment: Only if you use CDI, which the OP is not doing.